# repeat the first word and separate by tab

Tags: unix, replace, awk

I have a file describing bacteria taxanomy:

```
Yersinia aldovae       1
Yersinia frederiksenii  1
Yersinia pestis 2
Zymomonas mobilis   1
```

I want to make a new column to keep the first word of the bacteria name, like:

```
Yersinia   Yersinia aldovae    1
Yersinia   Yersinia frederiksenii   1
Yersinia   Yersinia pestis  2
Zymomonas   Zymomonas mobilis   1
```

Can some one tell me how to use sed or awk to do this job? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '{ print $1 "\t" $0 }' file
```

or perhaps:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{ print $1, $0 }' file
```

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) .*/\1\t&/' file
```

or:

```
sed 's/[^ ]*/&\t&/' file
```

Comment: One more `awk '$1=$1"\t"$1'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{print $1 "\t" $0}' source_file > dest_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also does the job!

Answer (score 2):

With **awk**:

```
awk '$0=$1"\t"$0' File
```

change the `"line"` to `"first column", tab & "line"` .

With **sed**:

```
sed -r 's/(\S+).*/\1\t&/' File
```

`(\S+)` => 1 or more non space characters, which will be the first word. Change the entire line to `"first word", tab and the line itself (&)`

Answer (score 1):

Print the first column and whole line.

```
awk '{printf("%s\t%s\n", $1, $0)}' filename > new_filename
```

Comment: That should produce a syntax error. ITYM `'{printf("%s\t%s\n", $1, $0)}'` but a simple print is enough